# sigsuspend() with SIGINT and SIGCHLD

Tags: c, operating-system, computer-science, cpu-architecture, signal-handling

I am studying this piece of code from the CSAPP book:

```
#include "csapp.h"

volatile sig_atomic_t pid;

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    int olderrno = errno;
    pid = Waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    errno = olderrno;
}

void sigint_handler(int s)
{
}

#define N 10
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    sigset_t mask, prev;
    int n = N; /* 10 */
    Signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);
    Signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
    Sigemptyset(&mask);
    Sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);

    while (n--) {
        Sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &prev); /* Block SIGCHLD */
        if (Fork() == 0) /* Child */
            exit(0);

        /* Wait for SIGCHLD to be received */
        pid = 0;
        while (!pid) 
            Sigsuspend(&prev);

        /* Optionally unblock SIGCHLD */
        Sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &prev, NULL); 

        /* Do some work after receiving SIGCHLD */
        printf(".");
    }
    printf("\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

While I understand a large part of it such as how sigsuspend uses mask and interacts with SIGCHLD, I don't understand this piece from the book *`If the parent caught a SIGINT, then the loop test succeeds and the next iteration calls sigsuspend again. If the parent caught a SIGCHLD, then the loop test fails and we exit the loop. At this point, SIGCHLD is blocked, and so we can optionally unblock SIGCHLD.`*

How does SIGINT interact with sigsuspend()? How will loop test succeed if SIGINT gets caught by parent? I guess the behavior of SIGINT is overwritten by the call to Signal(), which gets overwritten to doing nothing?

Also, how is SIGCHLD still blocked after loop test fails(by sigchld_handler())?

Much thanks in advance!

Other than this, can someone please do a walkthrough of this whole example? I don't have a solid understanding after reading it multiple times.

Comment: The sigint handler doesn't modify `pid` like the sigchld handler does, hence the loop test remaining true.

Comment: And sigchld is still blocked because nothing unlocks it until later.

Comment: Why is it necessary to register singint handler with Signal()?

Comment: I don't know why it does that.